# How to migrate all work items from Jazz RTC to TFS 2012?

Tags: rtc

We are moving from RTC to TFS and we need to somehow migrate our existing work items from RTC to TFS 2012. Is there a tool or plugin that would allow us to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you can:

- [export work from RTC through Excel](https://jazz.net/library/article/522/)
  [image: export]
- [bulk import work items to TFS through an Excel spreadsheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd286627.aspx)
  [image: import]

You can try and see how an excel export / import could work to get all your work items from RTC to TFS.